# ftruncate64 incorrect file size on gpfs with SUCCESS

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, filesystems

I could not reproduce this problem in the application with just trimmed 4 calls bellow, but it is consistent with my single threaded application on gpfs filesystem.

Important sequence of calls is

```
const int64_t capacity = 8458240;    
ftruncate64(fd, current_size + capacity);
fstat(fd, &buf);
munmap(base, capacity);
base = mmap64(nullptr, capacity, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, current_size);
```

It works on all file systems available here but gpfs.
Note: current_size is not rounded to capacity, but it is monotonically increasing.
So program and above calls run for a while successfully, until truncation of 5724962816. In this case the file adjusted on gpfs to only 5716836352 (exactly 5716MB). Smaller sizes works well.
It is  visible on strace output:

```
ftruncate(6, 5724962816)                = 0
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=5716836352, ...}) = 0
```

Have any suggestions to where to look farther?

Thank you in advance.

PS:
I was able to produce simple problem code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 auto m_fd = ::open(argv[1], O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) | (S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP));
long m_capacity =      8458240L;
long size = 60033856276L/8458240L;
long increment = 8417280L;
for(long i = 1; i<size; i++)
{
  if( ::ftruncate64(m_fd,  m_capacity + increment*i) < 0 )
  {
    std::cerr<<"ftruncate failed "<< errno << " "<<::strerror(errno) <<endl;
    return 1;
  }

  int8_t* base = (int8_t*)::mmap(nullptr, m_capacity, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, m_fd,  increment*i);
  if(base == MAP_FAILED)
  {
    std::cerr<<"mmap failed"<< errno << " "<<::strerror(errno) <<endl;
    return 1;
  }

  struct stat buf;
  ::fstat(m_fd, &buf);
  if(buf.st_size != m_capacity + increment*i)
    {
      std::cerr<< "size failed " << buf.st_size << " "<< (m_capacity + increment*i) <<  ", i " << i<<  endl;
      return 1;
    }

  for (int64_t i = 0; i < m_capacity; ++i)
    {
      volatile int8_t* addr = base + i;
      int8_t x              = *addr;
      *addr = x;
    }

  ::munmap(base, m_capacity);
}
return 0;
}
```

If i do return it will core after "failed 5716836352 5723791360, i 679"

Update:
I have created workaround, by basically calling second time ftruncate64 with same values if size mismatch.
Noticeable, I got second fail that is x2 of first one, so I probably will leave it to IBM.

size failed 5716836352 5723791360, i 679
size failed 11433672704 11439124480, i 1358

Comment: Did you mean `const int64_t capacity = 8458240L;`

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I was simplifying the code from the source